# iOS 14: Create album with new "Selected Photos..." permission? and Fetch AssetCollection For Album?

Tags: photo, selected, ios14

Step:1 In Gallery Permission i select "Selected Photos...".

Step:2 I create Custom Photo Album.

Step:3 And Try to Fetch AssetCollection from album.

Step:4 It give collection.firstObject = nil.

Step:5 It Work Good if i select Allow Access to All Photos.

For Create album i use  :

```
@objc func createAlbumIfNeeded() {
        if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
            // Album already exists
            print("album Already exist")
            self.assetCollection = assetCollection
        } else {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)   // create an assetadsasdasddsa colsadasdasddfsfsdfsfsdfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsddsdf,nbmbmnbmnbmnsdasdasdlection with the album name
            }) { success, error in
                if success {
                    self.assetCollection = self.fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
                    print("Album Created")
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    // Unable to create album
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

-> and For  Fetch AssetCollection For Album: -

```
  func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection? {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
        if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
            return collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: hey, got any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Selected Photos Option Which allow Selected Photos option in our application.

-> If you want to create album in Photo-library in iPhone So Allow Access to All Photos option is Compulsory but if you want to get photos from Photo-library Than Selected Photos  option will work.